# basicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code

Tags: android, android-volley

this code working on localhost but i have getting "basicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500" error if i put this file on online server

this is my important project...please help me....

```
private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Functions.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    JSONObject json_user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect email or password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: 500 is a server error!! check with server side script

Comment: ok...thank you bro :)

Comment: Thankme with a vote bro! Haha u are welcone

Answer (score 0):

500 is a server error! You should check your script!